# scrollview autolayout issue xcode 8 with constraints

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, constraints, scrollview

I am adding my intro screens in a scrollview.So I have to scroll horizontally only.I have set constraints for scrollview(top, bottom.leading, trailing).I have added subviews like the following

```
 for i in 0..<self.arrIntro.count{

                let view = IntroScreenView.instanceFromNib()
                let x = CGFloat(i) * self.scrollIntro.frame.size.width

                view.frame = CGRect(x: x, y: 0, width: self.scrollIntro.frame.size.width, height: self.scrollIntro.frame.size.height)
                print(view,self.scrollIntro)
                view.imgIntro.image = UIImage(named: "image-1")//UIImage(contentsOfFile: self.arrIntro[i]["Link"] as! String)
                print(self.arrIntro[i]["Link"] as! String)
                self.scrollIntro.addSubview(view)
            }
            self.scrollIntro.contentSize = CGSize(width: (CGFloat(self.arrIntro.count) * self.scrollIntro.frame.size.width ) , height: self.scrollIntro.frame.size.height)
```

but my scrollview is vertically scrolling little bit.How should I avoid this.Any autolayout issue?

Comment: Why don't you use a `UICollectionView`?

Answer (score 0):

You're not adding any constraints to your views. Add height and width constraints to each item, constraints between the views and constraints from the views to the scroll view. Note that the constraints between the Su views and the scroll view will set the content size for you.

Answer (score 0):

Scroll view scrolls vertically, when `contentSize.height` is greater than the `scrollView` height.

Just make sure, your `contentSize.height` is not greater than the `scrollView.frame.size.height`.

One reason, that I could guess is that, you might be setting `contentSize` a point after which the frames of the scroll view changes. You should move setting you contentSize in `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`

Sample : This code makes vertical scroll

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var scrollView: UIScrollView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.scrollView.bounds.width*5, height: self.scrollView.frame.height)
    }
}
```

And this does not

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var scrollView: UIScrollView!

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.scrollView.bounds.width*5, height: self.scrollView.frame.height)
    }
}
```